# Acro package: display pdfcomment only on short-form, matching single/plural case

Tags: acronyms, acro, pdfcomment

I want to use the Acro package to display the long-form acronyms only when hovering over short-form acronyms.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{soul}
\acsetup{
  pdfcomments/use=true
}
\DeclareAcronym{cth}{
  short = {CTH},
  long = {Change in Tariff Heading},
  long-plural-form = {Changes in Tariff Heading},
  pdfcomment = {\acroifTF{short}{\acl{cth}}{}},
}


\begin{document}
    First use: \ac{cth}\\
    Second use singular: \ac{cth}\\
    Third use plural: \acp{cth}
\end{document}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I modify this code so that whenever I hover over `\acp{cth}`, it displays "Changes in Tariff Heading" instead of "Change in Tariff Heading"?
2. Is it possible to avoid displaying the long form in the First use short form portion?

Solving question 1 is essential, solving number 2 would be a bonus but not critical.